# jquery Image slider without define width?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have used the coin slider.But the coin slider is restricted by the width.I need to run my application in various screen size like 1280*768,800*600.is there any image slider in jquery without restrict width of image?Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a question this vague (what have you tried, what went wrong, why without restricting the width..?) I can only point you to the [jQuery plugins page](http://plugins.jquery.com/).

Comment: What about using $(document).width() property? Depending on document width you can easily define width of your slider

Comment: Hi IgorM,I can't put the slider for the whole document.I have two column in the document.The first column only contains coin slider.The second column contains the login panel.According to the width of the second column,the first column was adjust.So Is there any otherway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most image sliders are designed for being placed within a container of a certain width, so that they fit within a specific slot in a layout. Given that the size of the screen/window(you don't specify) is irrelevant to that, it seems like what you're looking for is a gallery that adapts to the size of the entire window, rather than fit within a specific size.

You should probably widen your search to JS galleries in general, which might have that option or even function that way in the first place. As initial suggestions, have a look at the full-screen example for [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/), or maybe the [Supersized plugin](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)